# App store app submission from Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

We have an app from the client which is written in Obj-c and includes Swift submodules written in Swift 2.3.
As of now, I am running it on Xcode 8.2.1. By May 15, 2017, Apple has made it mandatory to upload app from Xcode 8.3.1 or above. 
I may have converted the Swift 2.3 files to Swift 3, but since they are submodules of external framework, these files are locked.
My query is can I upload app by this week using Xcode 8.2.1 or do I requires version above that?

Comment: Do you have a link to the Apple Docs that states May 15, 2017?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/release-notes/
And sorry its 10 May, 2017

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you're reading that sort-of "out of context."

From the link ( https://developer.apple.com/testflight/release-notes/ ):

- May 1, 2017

  - iTunes Connect

    - Starting May 10, 2017, app archives built with Xcode 8.3 will no longer be accepted. Make sure to build and submit your apps using Xcode 8.3.1 or later.

and further on that page...

- April 6, 2017

  - iTunes Connect

    - Xcode 8.3.1 fixed an issue that could produce app archives that were larger than necessary. Support for app archives built in Xcode 8.3 will be deprecated.

The way I read it - and considering there are no other references on that page to Xcode version limits - that is referring *only* to 8.3 vs 8.3.1 (or later), and *not* to 8.2

Also note, *currently* at iTunesConnect:

[image]

Comment: So according to you it will be possible to upload build from Xcode 8.2.1?

Comment: That is how I read it. Also, when I go to iTunesConnect I see ***"Submit your builds using Xcode 6 or later, or Application Loader 3.0 or later."*** So, again, based on what I am reading, it seems to indicate that **only 8.3** is being dropped.

Comment: Ok thank you  for your help. Will update this post if I am successful in uploading the same.